# HashMap returns null when fetching with present key object with same hashCode value and equals = true

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, hashmap

I am using objects of type **Question** as the keys in a HashMap. I implemented the `hashCode()` and `equals` functions as shown below.

**Question.kt**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class Question(
    val id: Int,
    val question:String
) : Parcelable{
    @Ignore
    @IgnoredOnParcel
    var isQuestionDimmed: Boolean = false

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Question

        if (id != other.id) return false
        if (isQuestionDimmed != other.isQuestionDimmed) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id
        result = 31 * result + isQuestionDimmed.hashCode()
        return result
    }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}

fun Question.clone(): Question {
    val question = Question(id,question)
    question.isQuestionDimmed = isQuestionDimmed
    return question
}
```

Now I create my HashMap as such:

```
val hm:LinkedHashMap<Question, QuestionAnswerDetails> = hashMapOf()
```

Now, I expect that when I try to fetch the value of a certain key, the HashMap would use the hashCode() and equals() functions under the hood to locate the pre-inserted value.

This always works, except if I modify a key's "isQuestionDimmed" property. Then, after that, fetching that key always returns null! Although the key exists and has the same hashCode as the key object I am searching with and the equals() function returns true.

Here's a screenshot of my debugging in action:
[image]

Comment: Did you modify the keys after they went into the map?  Say, by changing the value of `isQuestionDimmed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using objects as keys in HashMaps, you have to make sure that you satisfy the below conditions:

**Updated thanks to @cactustictacs**

1. The key object implements hashCode() fun
2. The key object implements equals() fun
3. The key object properties used in hashCode() and equals() implementation are immutable (Not necessarily the whole key object to be immutable)

---

**Why override equals() and hashCode()?**

If a class does not override the equals() and hashCode() methods of the Object class and an object of such class is used as a key for map or set in Java, the default implementation of these methods is used which simply checks for reference equality. [Reference](https://www.techiedelight.com/how-to-use-equal-objects-as-key-hashmap-hashset-java/) Thus, you will only be able to access Map values using the exact same key object which you used to add the value originally.

**Why should the key object properties used in hashCode() and equals() implementation be immutable?**

Because, when first defining let’s say value v1 to k1, the place in memory assigned for (k1,v1) depends on the hashcode calculated the first time (k1,v1) is added to the hashMap according to the hashcode of k1. If you later modify a k1 property that is used in hashCode(), its hashcode will become different but the place in memory for (k1,v1) will remain the same according to the original hashcode of k1. Thus, if you try to fetch the hashmap using k1 after modifying it, the result will be null as it will point to a new location in memory with nothing assigned to it. Same thing for equals(), the properties used in it should be immutable to be able to maintain only unique keys in the HashMap.

**How to fix the above code?**

Luckily, since Kotlin's data classes give you default implementations of hashCode() and equals() that only use the properties in the primary constructor, we can simply rewrite the code as follows:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class Question(
    val id: Int,
    val question:String
) : Parcelable{
    @Ignore
    @IgnoredOnParcel
    var isQuestionDimmed: Boolean = false
}
```

Now, you can change the value of `isQuestionDimmed` freely

Comment: The key doesn't have to be immutable, you just can't change any properties that would make ``hashCode()`` return a different value, or make ``equals()`` return false. Data classes give you default implementations that only use the properties in the primary constructor, so you'd be able to change ``isQuestionDimmed`` and it would still be considered equal and give the same hash. You're explicitly including it in your overrides and saying it's **not** equal if that value doesn't match, and you're including it in your hashcode, so you're intentionally introducing that behaviour here